# How to display images from mysql database using asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am using MySQL, I stored my images as `varchar` in the database, how can I display those images? Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
public static DataTable GetAllMydetails()
{
    string connString = "Server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;";
    string query = "SELECT `Mydetails`.`Image`";

    MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    ma.Fill(DS);

    return DS.Tables[0];    
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // I want to display image here on page load...//
}
```

Comment: Store images in database is usually more expensive than stores in the file storage. The usual approach is store the images paths in the database rather than the image.

Answer (score 0):

How could you store that image in varchar? Means you stored image name or converted into bytes and then stored?

Because we can't directly store image without using image data type.

So can you please be brief?